# Jquery datatables plugin for django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datatable

I am newbie to django. I am using jquery datatable plugins in my django application. These datatables are working fine for the small datasets sent from my view. I have a django model which is having 65k records with 5 columns. when I am trying to show these records in jquery datatables the rendered page becoming unresponsive for a moment and the page is loading correctly. Also sorting, searching, pagination features are working fine with reasonable to amount of time. I want to see the page responsive even when I am showing 65k entries in datatables. Is there any way to do this? or what will be the best solution to handle large datasets? Pls suggest me

I came to know that this is because I am trying to format datatables on client side after loading 65k records from the server. Also I googled n knew that server side processing will be the best way to handle this. Any one pls suggest me how to do server side processing in django.

Now, my code is as follows:

part of Inventory.html:

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive" id='postinfo'>

</div>
```

InventoryOutputAlldata.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     $('#example1').dataTable({
        });

      });
    </script>
</head>

        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Device</th>
                    <th>Device Type</th>
                    <th>Mac Address</th>
                    <th>IP Address</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >
            <form name="trform" method="post">
              {% for key,value in data.items %}

                <tr  class="trselected" onclick="trclick(this)"> 

                        <td>{{ value.0 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.3 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ value.4 }}</td>
                  </tr>
              {% endfor %}
             </form>
              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Device</th>
                    <th>Device Type</th>
                    <th>Mac Address</th>
                    <th>IP Address</th>
                    <th>Status</th>                                           
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

</html>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var data = new Object();
    data['showdata'] = 'all';
    data["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
    $( "#postinfo" ).load( "/alldata/", data, function( response, status, xhr )
    {

    });
});
```

URLs.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^inventory/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='inventory.html')),
    url(r'^alldata/$', 'NetworkInventory.nmap_integration.alldata'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def alldata(request):
    postedInfo = request.POST
    count = 0
    dataDict = {}

    dbData = nmap.objects.all()
    if 'showdata' in postedInfo and postedInfo['showdata'] == 'all':
        for data in dbData:
            count += 1
            dataDict[count] = []
            dataDict[count].append(data.device)
            dataDict[count].append(data.devicetype)
            dataDict[count].append(data.macaddress)
            dataDict[count].append(data.ipaddress)
            dataDict[count].append(data.status)

    else:
        return HttpResponse('Improper Behaviour')

    return render_to_response('inventoryOutputAlldata.html',{'data': dataDict})
```

Please suggest me how can i modify this to work with large datasets.

Comment: don't use `Jquery datatables plugin` use django modelforms and lazy pagination

Comment: @madzohan, could u pls suggest docs for django modelforms and lazy pagination?

Answer (score 0):

When you do it that way all of the records are loaded into cache. You need to use iterate.
Perhaps this is what you want.

```
car_set = Car.objects.all()
for car in car_set.iterator():
    #Do something
```

**Or more advanced**

[djangosnippets](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1949/) 
Try this

```
import gc

def queryset_iterator(queryset, chunksize=1000):
    '''''
    Iterate over a Django Queryset ordered by the primary key

    This method loads a maximum of chunksize (default: 1000) rows in it's
    memory at the same time while django normally would load all rows in it's
    memory. Using the iterator() method only causes it to not preload all the
    classes.

    Note that the implementation of the iterator does not support ordered query sets.
    '''
    pk = 0
    last_pk = queryset.order_by('-pk')[0].pk
    queryset = queryset.order_by('pk')
    while pk < last_pk:
        for row in queryset.filter(pk__gt=pk)[:chunksize]:
            pk = row.pk
            yield row
        gc.collect()
```

Comment: your view is about server side memory, but for me there is no difference in using dbname.objects.all() or queryset_iterator() as I am facing the problem on client side. My views function is able to post the large data to the client in reasonable amount of time. But on client side jquery datatables are unable to handle this large data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a page loader for this. You can set the page loader to the time taken for your datatable rendered correctly into the page.